# Can you have multiple domains for a single openshift app?

Tags: openshift

Can you have multiple domains for a single openshift app?

Heroku is allowing this. Either completely different domains( app.abc.com, app.xyz.com ) or subdomains ( *.abc.com, *.xyz.com ).

Is it possible with openshift? What about SSL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can assign multiple aliases to an application, but you can only install one ssl certificate per application afaik.

Comment: Where can you do this in the UI?

Comment: Click on your application, then click on "change" by your url at the top, then you can add aliases, custom ssl is for Silver plan users only.

Comment: The ui is confusing, but I see I can add another one afterward. Unfortunately, there is not wildcard accepted (*.example.com), so if I provide a domain for each customer I need to go in there and add an alias each time.

Comment: You could also do it programmatically via the OpenShift API: https://www.openshift.com/sites/default/files/documents/OpenShift_Online-2.0-REST_API_Guide-en-US_3.pdf